# #define StrToInt StrToIntA causes external reference error

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile an old project that contains a class named CVUtil with a function 
called `StrToInt(char *, int *)`. 
This function is called on several locations in the project with the syntax  `CVUtil::StrToInt(pSomeChar,pSomeInt)`.
When trying to compile this project VisStudio will change `StrToInt` to `StrToIntA` since somewhere the file Shlwapi.h is included and in it is the preprocessor statement
`"#define StrToInt  StrToIntA"`. I Know that I can avoid this with just changing the name of the  function but would like to find out how I can avoid this without doing that.
Regards, Arni

Answer (score 1):

You could `#undef StrToInt` in the header that contains the class definition, but the correct way would be to rename the function.

Comment: The correct (if impractical way) would be for Microsoft not to use macros for this ugly way to choose between ...A and ...W functions variants. There are just so many common function names that get blatted. </rant>

Answer (score 0):

You can always undefine the previous definition:

```
#ifdef StrToInt
#undef StrToInt
#endif
#define StrToInt StrToIntA
```

However a better way would still be to pick another name.

Answer (score -1):

You better adjust your linker settings. Refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc for details about *A (Ascii) and *W (Wide) functions. The article explains how to adjust the visual studio settings.

The directive

```
#define fun funA
```

should be guarded by something like this:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
# define fun funW
#else
# define fun funA
#endif
```

Comment: what does linker have to do with compilation error? the problem is that MS headers do the `#ifdef` part, but this also affects the `CVUtil` class as it is included before it.

Comment: ah, you are right, i completely forgot the question title :) however, the problem is created during compilation (actually preprocessing) phase. changing the character type as in the referenced article won't help because it will just result in error being caused by `StrToIntW` instead of `StrToIntA` - linker complains because the signature of modified  `StrToIntA` doesn't fit the other one.

Comment: I see, the `CVUtil::StrToInt` is 'intercepted' by some windows definition, which incidentally interferes with the CVUtil code?

Comment: Right, and most of windows APIs which have string parameters exhibit the same potential to cause problems.